# MVC URL RedirectToAction URl has variable and its parameter in Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am Redirecting my Action to another urls woth optional parameter and passing variable to    the controller

```
RedirectToAction("action", new { a, c, s,ds});

but my urls loosk like this 

http://localhost:8080/contoller/action?a=1&c=2&s=3&ds=4

but when i directly call teh action the url looks like this 

http://localhost:8080/contoller/action/1/2/3/4

how can i get the same url with redirect ..any suggestion
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this? (I'm not sure if it works)

```
    RedirectToAction("action", new { a = a, c = c, s = s,ds = ds});
```

A dirty method is:

```
    Redirect("/area/home/action?a=" + a + "&b=" + b + "&c=" + c + "&ds=" + ds);
```

In fact I use the second one quite often, because it's clearer to see all the parameters and values. The only shortage is that if there is any error in the url, there is no warnings.